# Sails.js regex routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, sails.js

I am building a simple sails.js project and implementing the front end with backbone.

Ideally I want a single route to the one index page in which my backbone app is served.

```
'/*': {
    view: 'home/index'
}
```

This is great, so any URL now goes to the homepage. Except now, all the routes to any assets (.js, .css, .html, .jpg) do not work anymore.

I can see this comment in the `config.routes.js`:

```
// NOTE:
// You'll still want to allow requests through to the static assets,
// so we need to set up this route to ignore URLs that have a trailing ".":
// (e.g. your javascript, CSS, and image files)
'get /*(^.*)': 'UserController.profile'
```

But it doesn't make any sense to me. How do I ignore routes with a file extensions.

I have also prefixed all my CRUD url's with 'api', `localhost:1337/api/controller/` so a regex route to exclude forwarding those would also be required. I cannot find any information on how to do this anywhere.

I must be missing something fundamental here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the skipAssets and skipRegex flags. This will not step on your static assets and will not block your api urls starting with /api. I use this with sails.js and angular in html5Mode.

```
  "get *":{
    controller:"PagesController",
    action:"index",
    skipAssets: true,
    skipRegex: /^\/api\/.*$/
  }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! This is what i came for!

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak I dug through the SailsJS source to find skipAssets and skipRegex. Maybe they have documentation now, but when I wrote this there was no mention in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug but I found a workaround solution.

`'get /[^.?]+?': 'UserController.profile'`

or you can use other one. only `/user` and `/profile` will exec `UserController.profile`. static directory still work great.

`'get /:action( user | profile)': 'UserController.profile'`